# Meaning of probability as used in machine learning

Tags: machine-learning, probability

In machine learning, it seems that people are often happy to call the output of any function (e.g. logistic function) with the range $[0, 1]$, a probability.

How correct is that thinking? How compatible is it with probability theory?

It feels that there is more to probabilities, which is ignored in machine learning. I assume that it is for the sake of simplicity.

I should also mention that I don't have much of a background in probability theory, besides the basics that you need in machine learning. Any answers or guidance to other resources is much appreciated.

Comment: The answer to this question may depend on the model that is actually used. If we are taking for example the most simplistic neural network with a binary outcome variable, softmax and without a hidden layer we have a model that is equivalent to logistic regression. This model has deep roots in probability theory and statistics and its outcomes can be interpreted as probabilities. However, for more complicated models where no actual distribution is specified a reference with respect to probabilities might (but not necessarily) be misleading.

Comment: Could you explain a bit more how the probabilities of more complicated models could be misleading? Would they for example violate some of the axioms of probabilities?

Comment: In general you can interpret everything in terms of probability as long as you stay in a framework that satisfies the axions of probabilities. Hence, there is nothing wrong with interpreting any outcomes that satisfy them as probabilities. However, I do not feel fully comfortable with interpreting any number between zero and one as a probability if no underlying distribution is assumed.

Comment: I see. Thank you very much for your answers.